# Android BluetoothDevice notify remote unbond change state

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, bluecove

**Problem:** I am being notified when a bluetooth device is pairing, or becomes paired. However, I do not know how to get notified when a device is being unpaired. **How could I get my app to recognize when it has become unpaired with my device?**

**Example:** Let's say that I pair my surface tablet and my android phone through code. My broadcast receiver will register the `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED` intent and allow me to process it however I want. **Now, if I want to unpair my surface tablet, I do not get notified on my phone that the device has become unpaired. If I check, `device.getBondState()` for the device after it has been unpaired, it equals `BOND_BONDED` (which it clearly isnt)** I can get it to recognize it is unpaired again after I try to connect to the unpaired device, then the app crashes and then when I turn the app on again, only then does it recognize it as unpaired.

**Scenario:** I have a `BroadcastReceiver` registered to listen for intents caused by a BluetoothDevice

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED));
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));
```

I process these Actions with this `BroadcastReciever`:

```
final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        System.out.println("ACTION: "+ action);
        // When discovery finds a device

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        list();

        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        System.out.println("FOUND: " + device.getName() + " STATE: " + device.getBondState());
        mapInput(device);

        // Add the name and the mac address of the object to the array adapter
        BTSimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        System.out.println("UPDATE Name " + device.getName() + " Value " + device.getAddress() + " Bond state " + device.getBondState());
        for (Map<String, String> entry : data) {
            if (entry.get("Name").equals(device.getName()) && entry.get("Value").equals(device.getAddress())) {
                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    entry.put("Paired", "Unpaired");
                } else if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    entry.put("Paired", "Pairing");
                } else {
                    entry.put("Paired", "Paired");
                }
                BTSimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Comment: How do you unpair the device: programmatically or externally?

Comment: @cyanide I unpair it externally

Comment: This helped me to monitor pairing for my device. After receiving this broadcast I just check a list of bonded devices with `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices()`.